# Are there any other instances of a coach's challenge backfiring?

Tags: trivia, american-football, nfl, video-review

My title just refers to ​"coach's challenge" ​so it will be shorter. I intend to also include other non-neutrally-initiated [replay review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_replay#Use_by_officials), such as for example ​[manager's challenges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_replay_in_Major_League_Baseball) .

The one instance I am aware of is from [the 2017 Nov 12 NFL game Packers vs Bears](http://www.sj-r.com/sports/20171112/challenge-backfires-on-bears),
in which the original ruling was ​ Bears ball at the 3 yard line,
the Bears coach challenged hoping for a ruling of ​ touchdown by the Bears,
and the challenge resulted in a ruling of ​turnover, Packers ball.

Are there any other instances of a non-neutrally-initiated [replay review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_replay#Use_by_officials) backfiring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Jim Schwartz's attempted challenge against the Texans in 2012](http://wibx950.com/wierd-call-in-lions-texans-thanksgiving-day-game/) probably counts here. What happened:

- Texans running back Justin Forsett was knocked down, but got up and continued to run. The play was called a touchdown.
- As this was a scoring play, it was subject to automatic review.
- Jim Schwartz threw his challenge flag. Because the play was already subject to review, this was an illegal challenge.
- As the rules stood at the time, an illegal challenge prevented *all* review of the play, so the automatic review was cancelled.
- Therefore the touchdown stood, whereas it was highly likely that the automatic review would have called the touchdown back if Schwartz had not thrown his flag.

which was frankly a bit bonkers. For a less extreme example, see [Mike McCarthy's attempted challenge against the Vikings in 2012](http://wibx950.com/illegal-challenge-clarification-what-happened-in-packers-vikings-touchdown-review-call/). That was a similar situation, except that McCarthy threw his flag *after* the official replay had begun, so the replay happened and gave the Packers a touchdown. The Packers still got a a 15 yard penalty on the kickoff though.

[In the 2013 offseason, the NFL got rid of the rule that hammered the Lions because everybody agreed it was a bit silly](https://deadspin.com/5986035/the-nfl-will-get-rid-of-its-dumbest-rule).